# Java Bytecode - Register 1 contains wrong type

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, jasmin

I am currently stuck on the following problem:

Trying to execute the code below, I get the java error of "Register 1 containing the wrong type". Since I am only working with 1 stack-block integers I really wonder how the wrong type got in that register. Below is my jasmin-java-bytecode, it compiles fine but when executing it throws that error.

.class public HelloWorld
.super java/lang/Object

```
.method public static fakultaet(I)I
 .limit locals 100
 .limit stack 100

ldc 4

istore 0


ldc 1

istore 2
START: 
iload 0

iload 2

isub 
ifne ENDE 
iload 0

ldc 1

imul
istore 1

iload 2

ldc 1

iadd
istore 2

goto START 
ENDE: 
getstatic java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
iload 1

invokevirtual java/io/PrintStream/println(I)V

iload 1
ireturn


.end method
.method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
.limit stack 100
.limit locals 100



ldc 1

istore 0


ldc 2.0

fstore 1


ldc 3

istore 2

ldc 3

ldc 2

iadd
istore 0

ldc 3

invokestatic HelloWorld/fakultaet(I)I

return 

.end method
```

And this is the error generated:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: HelloWorld, method: fakultaet signature: (I)I) Register 1 contains wrong type
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2451)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2694)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1622)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so familiar with Jasmin (eh... the software), but it seems like there are several issues here: You are storing to register 1, although it might not have been initialized. Adding

```
ldc 1
istore 1
```

in front of your `START` label makes it compile and load the class, at least.

But it still only prints `1` which is not the desired result. As far as I can see, the condition

```
ifne ENDE
```

should actually be

```
ifeq ENDE
```

because you want to run the loop *while* difference between the counter and the argument is *not* zero (so it should go to the end when the counter and the argument are equal, i.e. when their difference *is* zero).

Additionally, the following part (the actual loop)

```
...
ifeq ENDE 
iload 0
ldc 1
imul
istore 1
iload 2
ldc 1
iadd
istore 2
goto START
```

keeps on multiplying the parameter with 1. You could/should instead increase the counter, and multiply the result with this counter in each pass:

```
...
ifeq ENDE 
iload 2
ldc 1
iadd
istore 2
iload 1
iload 2
imul
istore 1
goto START
```

BTW: While digging into this, I got help from [jd-gui](http://jd.benow.ca/) : You can just drag-and-drop the `.class` file into the decompiler window, and see whether the code makes any sense.